# Follow-redirects setting for AWS appsync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to invoke an HTTP endpoint from an Appsync resolver. But the HTTP endpoint is returning a 302 (redirect). The resolver does not automatically use the URL in the Location HTTP header, and redirect to that URL. The resolver stops after 302 and returns an empty resultset.

Can AWS perform the redirection automatically and get the final response or does this have to be coded in the resolver. And if it needs to be coded in, is there a sample available.

Comment: Figured it out. Used a pipeline resolver with 2 functions. First function receives the 301 or 302. Use the Location header field value. Second function uses that value to get the actual data and a 200 OK.